# A better way to search for answers?

Tags: support, search

Im sure this has been answered on SU before: [Redirect ip-address to localhost](https://superuser.com/questions/608880/redirect-ip-address-to-localhost)

However, Im doing a site search and cant find "the" answer.  I tried "port forwarding" and "port forwarding how to" and there are just way to many to sort through.  There has to be a better way.

It would be nice if there were a way to mark an answer as "best" when it comes to key words, so they pop to the top for easy access.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Add `isaccepted:yes` or `hasaccepted:yes` to the search keywords to search for answers which are accepted or have accepted answers

---

What is 'best' is subjective, and we have voting for that. You can apply minimum scores to search criteria: adding `score:2` will search and fetch all answers having a minimum score(ie upvotes - downvotes) of 2.